# Does ifdown wlan0 also switch off integrated Wifi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, pi-zero-w

For an embedded usecase I want my Pi users to be able to temporarily "switch off" WLAN/Wifi. Does `ifdown wlan0` only bring down the interface or does it also switch of the WLAN sender/receiver? What additional steps do I need to take in order to temporarily switch off `wlan` TX/RX completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifdown wlan0` prevents the OS from initiating any TX/RX operation on the interface. The RPi shouldn't be transmitting anything at this point, and you won't be able to scan for wireless networks until you bring the interface up again.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you may also want to disable Bluetooth, since WiFi and Bluetooth share the antenna and parts of the transceiver.

If you want to guarantee that no communication takes place (as much as you can guarantee something on a closed-source hardware), you'll have to disable WLAN and BT drivers in `/etc/modprobe.conf` and reboot:

```
#wifi
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmutil
#bt
blacklist btbcm
blacklist hci_uart
```

This will prevent the firmware from being uploaded into the adapter.

Comment: SInce I only need temporary switch-off -- kind of "flight mode" -- it should be sufficient for me to bring the interface down.

Comment: To be really on the safe side, I'm now using `rfkill block 0` to disable Wifi on the TX/RX level.

Comment: @TheDiveO Good point about `rfkill`

Comment: The advantage of `rfkill` is (at least I think so) that it also works when the firmware alrady has been downloaded.

Comment: @TheDiveO According to the [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ifconfig/), `ifconfig` will attempt to disable reception if supported by the driver. I doubt `rfkill` can do anything in addition to that.

Comment: @Dimitry Grigoryev good catch! I had missed that. Thanks for clarifying.